# Running Android Studio in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

Recently I've installed Android Studio on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, and it installed and runs - but I can't figure out how to run it once I closed it. When I try to run the studio.sh file, it shows me the installation process again - and messes up the files I already created. 
How can I just start the program without having to "install" it every time?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: have you complete installation any time ? then it never ask you again again.

Comment: Where did u install? Should do in a child directory of /home/user

Comment: @RobertRowntree It is installed in the path you mentiones (under Downloads).

Comment: @HareshChhelana  What? If you ask whether I completed the installation, then yes - the program installed and ran at least once.

Comment: review n make sure u did not do something with a package MGr. Review 'find . -name 'studio.sh' making sure not multiples. Then, do a complete reinstall of AS 1.0 after completely rm the old folder contents. Im on 12.04 and i cant see how that process would not work on 14.04 as long as you unpack to folders where you have permissions ( ie under /home/$yourUserName... )

Comment: @RobertRowntree I've tried opening it today and it worked like a charm. sometimes Ubuntu's skill to just have a bad day or something dazzles me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because this time you are not running it as root. Once you run the installation process, now start with root permissions:
Try first

```
su root
```

then

```
./bin/studio.sh
```

or use

```
sudo ./bin/studio.sh
```

This time **Android Studio** will start.

Comment: Android studio is not very kind to ubuntu. So much pain!

Comment: In my case after running above mentioned command I get following line and then execution does not move forward,   " Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0"

Comment: I had to use sudo or I would get the error: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main` using Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0):

Try create a new folder in directory : /home/user. unzip the files and try running again. 
try to do this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEQIwKK7YjY

Comment: OP is using Android Studio and not Eclipse.!

Answer (score 0):

When you exit studio.sh it pops up a window asking you if you want to run setup on the next start up something like that, I can't remember the exact verbage, you need to click the button that says no. Now when you start up it doesn't go through the set up again.